# Adding reference to Class Library issue in ASP.NET 5 beta 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I removed `dnxcore50` from project.json and added an empty class library to solution. When I add reference to class library, project build correctly but when I want to publish project, I will get this error:

```
The expected lock file doesn't exist. Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file
```

`dnu restore` command also not helps.

If i remove reference to class library, publish works fine.

project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-AdsProject-e7d42575-2bc4-4316-881a-236435c407a1",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug" : "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
        }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you resolved all reference warnings and don't mix different beta versions.
Are both versions still in beta7 incl your visual studio??

Try upgrade to beta 8 all projects, dnvm,dnx and visual studio

See the [home repro](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases)

Comment: Class Library targeted dotNet Framework 4.5.1.
I tried beta 8. and stuck in another issue there: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/449

Comment: Are you complete back to beta 7? tooling and dnx. What is your active dnx version if you run dnvm list? Do have any reference errors with dnu restore?

Comment: beta 7 x86 is default runtime. I had this problem before upgrading to beta 8 too. dnu restore has no error but problem not fixed.

Comment: If you have no reference warnings and your default runtime is also your active runtime (*). Have you tried running with dnx . web from the command line

Comment: Make sure to run `dnvm upgrade` to ensure you have the latest runtime and go in your project properties to ensure you have `beta8` selected as the executing runtime. If not already, make sure you have the tooling installed. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late. I had the exact same issue on beta 7 today. And only with custom libs added.

I got it fixed by going into the folder called "wrap" that gets created when you add your library. In there you'll find a project.json. Run a dnu restore on that folder in cmd.

Worked like a charm for me.